# Чтение файла если он занят другим процессом (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)

Tags: c#, файлы, filestream

Как мне читать файл, чтобы не вылезала эта ошибка:
`The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

Суть в том, что файл уже занят другим процессом но мне все равно необходимо его читать.

```cs
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filePath)) 
{
    string line = "";
    while ((line = await sr.ReadLineAsync()) != null) 
    {
        if (line.IndexOf("steamId=", StringComparison.Ordinal) <= 0 && line.IndexOf("steamid=", StringComparison.Ordinal) <= 0) continue;
        string[] splitLine = line.Split('|');
        string lineWrite = splitLine[1];
        CustomSql.ExecuteQuery($"INSERT INTO `log_admin` (`action`) VALUES ('${lineWrite}')");
        _lastVppLine = line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам уже дано решение. Если файл занят другим процессом, а не другим потоком вашего приложения, то вы никак не сможете прочитать этот файл до тех пор, пока блокируещее файл стороннее приложение его не отпустит.